# Left-hand limit definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I have the following definition:

> Let $I\subseteq \Bbb R$ be an open interval and let $c\in I$. A function $f:I \setminus \{c\}\rightarrow \Bbb R$ has a left hand limit in the point $c$ equal to $L$ if:
>
> $$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(\forall x\in I)((0<c-x<\delta)\Rightarrow(|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)).$$
> Then we say that $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=L.$

Can someone please explain this definition with an example or tell me where I can find some help on understanding this definition?

Comment: Informally it means: no matter what size interval around L you give me (on the y axis), I can find an interval on the x axis of the form (c- something ositive, c) such that ALL the points from that interval map to something within the interval around L you gave me.

Comment: $c\in I^\circ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the graph of 
$$f(x) = \left\{  \array{x & (x < 1) \\ x+1 & (x\ge 1)} \right.$$
The left hand limit of $f$ at $x=1 $ is $=1$, the right hand limit (defined similarly) is $=2$